# Windows 7 Encrypt Folder with Password

Tags: windows-7, passwords, encryption

First of all, I am not on Windows 7 at the moment but will be in the next few days.  I'd like to know if there is a way for me to encrypt a folder to prevent unwanted access, but still provide relatively easy access for myself.

Ideally, I'd like to have a folder that asks for a password when a user tries to access it, and allows me to work with it until I close it, or until my "session" times out, or something similar.

I really don't want to be encrypting/decrypting the entire folder just to get access to a few files.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think you want is what's called "on-the-fly" encryption/decryption. This is provided by many encryption systems, including the most popular one (AFAIK), [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). Create an encrypted container file, mount it, then 'move' all your files in there. Of course, the first time around, you have to wait until all the files are encrypted.

Note: Truecrypt is no longer supported or in development, I recommend using Veracrypt which is based on the original source code of Truecrypt's and is under development and is supported.

https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/

Comment: I should note that since [TrueCrypt is no longer supported](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/58942), it should be considered insecure, and therefore it should no longer be recommended software.

Comment: @Moab I think you meant veracrypt not truecrypt...

Comment: The latest version of [VeraCrypt is here](https://veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html)

Answer (score 1):

One easy option that you could use is to create an encrypted, password-protected archive of the folder. You could use a program like [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (which can be loaded onto a USB flash drive) to do this. Open 7-Zip and navigate to where the folder is. Right-click it, and select "Add to archive" under the *7-Zip* menu. On the right side of the dialog box, you can choose encryption options and set a password there.

Answer (score -2):

In windows 7 you can encrypt folder and files in them by right clicking on the folder and choose properties, then click "advanced button on the general tab, then choose encrypt.

This does not however password protect that folder on the PC it was encrypted on, to do this I use FolderDefence

http://foldermagepro.com/content/blogcategory/13/28/

The program can be password protected, and should be done.

Comment: Domain doesn't seem to exist