# OneNote 2010 full notebook encryption?

Tags: encryption, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

in OneNote 2010 one can encrypt single tabs / categories - but how to encrypt a complete notebook, so that not just all existing tabs but also new tabs become automatically encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

You can use TrueCrypt to create a container. Then, under OneNote Options > Save & Backup, point the following path to a folder in your container.

1. Unfiled Notes Section
2. Backup Folder
3. Default Notebook Location
4. Cache file location

Additional Information
If you have already created notebooks before creating any container/encryption, check the following path for files that you may want to move/erase - C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote\14.0

Answer (score 2):

A OneNote notebook is actually a folder in the file system,
which contains each tab as a .one file.

Maybe you can encrypt the notebook folder with some other methods.

Ex:
[Windows 7 Encrypt Folder with Password](https://superuser.com/questions/159498/windows-7-encrypt-folder-with-password)

Answer (score 1):

You can use TrueCrypt to encrypt your save files, however anyone will still be able to access your information in the cached location. OneNote will not allow you to encrypt the cached location.