# Software to encrypt and store documents

Tags: windows-7, security, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Encrypt Folder with Password](https://superuser.com/questions/159498/windows-7-encrypt-folder-with-password)

Hi

I am looking for some free software which can securely store and encrypt my documents (e.g. a make a folder and can have it encrypted).

This is for Windows 7 x64 Ultimate and a single-user.

Thanks

Comment: To me, not a dupe because no password requirement.

Comment: @Scott. Yet the answers to both questions are the same. Interesting. It's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Lifehacker seems to have a good article about encrypting individual files and folders:

> http://lifehacker.com/software/vista/windows-vista-tip--encrypt-files-231815.php

The article refers to Windows Vista, but it works in Windows 7 Ultimate...Not Home Premium, however.  Hope that helps!

Comment: The only thing I would add is if you do use EFS to encrypt your files, be sure to backup your encryption certificate.  If you only backup your data, and do a bare metal install and restore the data, the files will be unreadable.

Comment: Also, because of a single user machine, and is a Windows 7 Ultimate, BitLocker may be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Give [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) a try.

Comment: to my knowledge, this does not do individual folders...am i correct?

Comment: @Studiohack Not directly, though you could create a truecrypt volume and mount it as a folder instead of as a root drive (G:\ or H:\ for example)