# Recommend free file folder locker/encryption software on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Encrypt Folder with Password](https://superuser.com/questions/159498/windows-7-encrypt-folder-with-password)

I have a folder which I want to encrypt with a password.

Could you recommend this kind of software on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) (which is open-source) is often considered one of the better solutions for this kind of task.

Comment: But it only provide transparent encryption, and the operations is a little complicated for a folder. I 'll have to mount the file and umount the file while I am not using the files.

Comment: "I 'll have to mount the file and umount the file while I am not using the files". Yes, but every encryption software will require you to do some kind of unlock/lock; that's the nature of encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Wel, if you could put what you want in a ZIP file, you could use [AXCrypt](http://www.axantum.com/axcrypt/)